# Is it possible to run Spring WebFlux and MVC (CXF, Shiro, etc.) services together in Undertow?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

We are looking at implementing a few services using the new Spring 5 "Reactive" API.

We currently use, somewhat dependent on MVC, Apache CXF and Apache Shiro for our REST services and security. All of this runs in Undertow now.

We can get one or the other to work but not both together.  It appears when we switch over to the reactive application it knocks out the servlets, filters, etc.  Conversely, when we use the MVC-style application it does not see the reactive handlers.

Is it possible to run the Spring 5 Reactive services alongside REST/servlet/filter components or customize the SpringBoot startup to run REST and Reactive services on different ports?

**Update:**

I "seem" to be able to get the reactive handlers working doing this but I don't know if this is the right approach.

```
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routeGoodbye(TrackingHandler endpoint)
{
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route = RouterFunctions
        .route(GET("/api/rx/goodbye")
                   .and(accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)), endpoint::trackRedirect2);

    return route;
}

@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routeHello(TrackingHandler endpoint)
{
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route = RouterFunctions
        .route(GET("/api/rx/hello")
                   .and(accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)), endpoint::trackRedirect);

    return route;
}

@Bean
ContextPathCompositeHandler servletReactiveRouteHandler(TrackingHandler handler)
{
    final Map<String, HttpHandler> handlers = new HashMap<>();
    handlers.put("/hello", toHttpHandler((this.routeHello(handler))));
    handlers.put("/goodbye", toHttpHandler(this.routeGoodbye(handler)));

    return new ContextPathCompositeHandler(handlers);
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(final ContextPathCompositeHandler handlers)
{
    ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(
        new ReactiveServlet(handlers),
        "/api/rx/*");

    registrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registrationBean.setAsyncSupported(true);
    return registrationBean;
}

@Bean
TrackingHandler trackingEndpoint(final TrackingService trackingService)
{
    return new TrackingHandler(trackingService,
                               null,
                               false);
}

public class ReactiveServlet extends ServletHttpHandlerAdapter
{
    ReactiveServlet(final HttpHandler httpHandler)
    {
        super(httpHandler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after playing around with this for too long I finally seemed to be able to cobble together a solution that works for me.  Hopefully this is the right way to do what I need to do.

Now, executing normal CXF RESTful routes shows me Undertow using a blocking task and executing my Reactive routes shows me undertow using NIO directly. When I tried using the ServletHttpHandler it looked like it was just invoking the service as a Servlet 3 async call.

The handlers are running completely separate from each other and allows me to run my REST services beside my reactive services.

**1) Create an annotation that will be used to map the RouterFunction to an Undertow Handler**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface ReactiveHandler
{
    String value();
}
```

**2) Create an UndertowReactiveHandler "Provider" so that I can lazily get the injected RouterFunction and return the UndertowHttpHandler when I configure Undertow.**

```
final class UndertowReactiveHandlerProvider implements Provider<UndertowHttpHandlerAdapter>
{
    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext context;
    private String path;
    private String beanName;

    @Override
    public UndertowHttpHandlerAdapter get()
    {
        final RouterFunction router = context.getBean(beanName, RouterFunction.class);
        return new UndertowHttpHandlerAdapter(toHttpHandler(router));
    }

    public String getPath()
    {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(final String path)
    {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void setBeanName(final String beanName)
    {
        this.beanName = beanName;
    }
}
```

**3) Create the NonBLockingHandlerFactory (implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor).  This looks for any of my @Bean methods that have been annotated with "ReactiveHandler" and then dynamically creates a "UndertowReactiveHandlerProvider" bean for each annotated router function which is used later to provide the handlers to Undertow.**

```
@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory) throws BeansException
{
    final BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry)configurableListableBeanFactory;
    final String[] beanDefinitions = registry.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    for (String name : beanDefinitions)
    {
        final BeanDefinition beanDefinition = registry.getBeanDefinition(name);
        if (beanDefinition instanceof AnnotatedBeanDefinition
            && beanDefinition.getSource() instanceof MethodMetadata)
        {
            final MethodMetadata beanMethod = (MethodMetadata)beanDefinition.getSource();
            final String annotationType = ReactiveHandler.class.getName();
            if (beanMethod.isAnnotated(annotationType))
            {
                //Get the current bean details
                final String beanName = beanMethod.getMethodName();
                final Map<String, Object> attributes = beanMethod.getAnnotationAttributes(annotationType);

                //Create the new bean definition
                final GenericBeanDefinition rxHandler = new GenericBeanDefinition();
                rxHandler.setBeanClass(UndertowReactiveHandlerProvider.class);

                //Set the new bean properties
                MutablePropertyValues mpv = new MutablePropertyValues();
                mpv.add("beanName", beanName);
                mpv.add("path", attributes.get("value"));
                rxHandler.setPropertyValues(mpv);

                //Register the new bean (Undertow handler) with a matching route suffix
                registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName + "RxHandler", rxHandler);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**4) Create the Undertow ServletExtension.  This looks for any UndertowReactiveHandlerProviders and adds it as an UndertowHttpHandler.**

```
public class NonBlockingHandlerExtension implements ServletExtension
{
    @Override
    public void handleDeployment(DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo, final ServletContext servletContext)
    {
        deploymentInfo.addInitialHandlerChainWrapper(handler -> {
            final WebApplicationContext ctx = getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);

            //Get all of the reactive handler providers
            final Map<String, UndertowReactiveHandlerProvider> providers =
                ctx.getBeansOfType(UndertowReactiveHandlerProvider.class);

            //Create the root handler
            final PathHandler rootHandler = new PathHandler();
            rootHandler.addPrefixPath("/", handler);

            //Iterate the providers and add to the root handler
            for (Map.Entry<String, UndertowReactiveHandlerProvider> p : providers.entrySet())
            {
                final UndertowReactiveHandlerProvider provider = p.getValue();

                //Append the HttpHandler to the root
                rootHandler.addPrefixPath(
                    provider.getPath(),
                    provider.get());
            }

            //Return the root handler
            return rootHandler;
        });
    }
}
```

**5) Under META-INF/services create a "io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension" file.**

```
com.mypackage.NonBlockingHandlerExtension
```

**6) Create a SpringBoot AutoConfiguration that loads the post processor if Undertow is on the classpath.**

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(Undertow.class)
public class UndertowAutoConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    BeanFactoryPostProcessor nonBlockingHandlerFactoryPostProcessor()
    {
        return new NonBlockingHandlerFactoryPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

**7) Annotate any RouterFunctions that I want to map to an UndertowHandler.**

```
@Bean
@ReactiveHandler("/api/rx/service")
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routeTracking(TrackingHandler handler)
{
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route = RouterFunctions
        .nest(path("/api/rx/service"), route(
            GET("/{cid}.gif"), handler::trackGif).andRoute(
            GET("/{cid}"), handler::trackAll));

    return route;
}
```

With this I can call my REST services (and Shiro works with them), use Swagger2 with my REST services, and call my Reactive services (and they do not use Shiro) in the same SpringBoot application.

In my logs, the REST call shows Undertow using the blocking (task-#) handler.  The Reactive call shows Undertow using the non-blocking (I/O-# and nioEventLoopGroup) handler